# Angularjs app not passing id of individual user to url

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular app with a list of users. When I click on edit, I need to pass a specific user id into the url and am having difficulty in doing do. I am getting an undefined id when I click on the edit button- www.example.com.users/undefined- and an error message in the console-

```
Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an object but got an array
```

The are lots of SO questions about this error, but seem to be the other way around whereby the response was expected to contain an array but got an object. I set `isArray` to false on the `show` method of my service anyway but to no effect.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

UserCtrl:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers')
    .controller('UserCtrl', ['$scope', 'UsersFactory', 'UserFactory', '$location',
    function ($scope, UsersFactory, UserFactory, $location) {



 //This is the function behind my edit button
    $scope.editUser = function (userId) {
        $location.path('/users/' + userId);
    };



    // callback for ng-click 'createUser':
    $scope.createNewUser = function () {
        $location.path('/users/new');
    };

    $scope.users = UsersFactory.query();
}]);
```

UserEditCtrl:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers')
    .controller('UserEditCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'UserFactory', '$location',
    function ($scope, $routeParams, UserFactory, $location) {

        // callback for ng-click 'updateUser':
        $scope.updateUser = function () {
            UserFactory.update($scope.user);
            $location.path('/users');
        };

//EDIT: This shows a value of "undefined"
 console.log($routeParams.userId);
        $scope.user = UserFactory.show({id: $routeParams.userId});

    }]);
```

Users Service:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp.services');

app.factory('UsersFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('https://example.com/users', {}, {
        query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
        create: { method: 'POST' }
    })
});

app.factory('UserFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('https://example.com/users/:id', {}, {
        show: { method: 'GET', isArray: false  },
        update: { method: 'PATCH', params: {id: '@id'} },
        delete: { method: 'DELETE', params: {id: '@id'} }
    })
});
```

Comment: See what you get in editUser when you do `console.log(userId)`

Comment: See edit made to UserEditCtrl

Comment: Did you try `$route.current.params.userId`?

Comment: Where would I try that?

Comment: In place of `$routeParams.userId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could actually use one factory for the resource

```
app.factory('UserFactory', function ($resource) {
return $resource('https://example.com/users/:id', null, 
   {
      update: { method: 'PATCH' }
   })
});
```

[AngularJS $resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource)

In your controller, you use `$scope.user = UserFactory.get({id: $routeParams.userId});` instead and `.query()` to return array.

You also need to make sure that the responses from the server are in the required format.

Note: This was AngularJS v1.2.5

Comment: I also need to show a list of users and be able to add, edit and delete, is this all possible with one factory?

Comment: Yes it is. You have `get`, `save`, `query`, `remove`, and `delete` as default actions. You only need to add `update` to implement the CRUD operations.

Comment: I tried this and it works fine for getting all users, however I am still getting the same error message and the id is not passed into the url. Any suggestions?

Comment: It is difficult for me to recreate the bug. However, if I was implementing this, I would perform all the CRUD operations in one controller. That would help in keeping related code in one place. With your implementation, you would probably need another controller for delete operation.